# pynput non-deterministic error when monitoring the keyboard

Tags: python, keyboard, pyautogui, pynput

I want to monitor the keyboard, and whenever the `Alt` key is pressed, I want to record the current position of the mouse.

My code is:

```
import pyautogui                                                                 
from pynput import keyboard                                                                                                                         
                                                                                 
def getMousePosition(trigger_key):                                               
    #Wait until the trigger_key is pressed                                       
    #And return the current position of the mouse                                
    with keyboard.Events() as events:                                            
        for event in events:                                                     
            if event.key == trigger_key:                                     
                return pyautogui.position()                                                                 
                                                                                                                 
def main():                                                                                                                           
    for i in range(100):                                                   
        position_one = getMousePosition(keyboard.Key.alt)                        
        print(f"Position found at {position_one}")                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
if __name__ == "__main__":                                                                                                                                                                                         
    main()
```

This works **most** of the times, but I have a problem that I haven't been able to track or reproduce consistently. Some times, when I press `Alt` it stops working, and I don't `print(Position found at (XXX,YYY))`. The program just hangs there until I do `ctrl + c`. Then, instead of dying, the program just moves on as if nothing has happened.

To be clear, when it fails I have to `ctrl +c` to bring it back into the `for i in range(100)` loop. Instead of dying it comes back.

I have tried to catch an exception and see why it is failing, but I don't get anything, it just hangs:

```
def getMousePosition(trigger_key):                                               
    #Wait until the trigger_key is pressed                                       
    #And return the current position of the mouse                                
    with keyboard.Events() as events:                                            
        for event in events: 
            try:                                                    
                if event.key == trigger_key:                                     
                    return pyautogui.position()
            except:
                print("Some error") #This never happens. It just hangs without returning some times
```

I have zero to none experience with python, so it would be very helpful if someone can point me into the right direction.